# Ubuntu full-install won't get past login (amd radeon gpu)

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, radeon

I have a [MSI GX70](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/gx70-3begx70.html) gaming computer that I converted into a coding computer. I installed Ubuntu but its GPU (**AMD Radeon HD 8970M**) is giving me trouble.

Ubuntu 14 + [Oibaf](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) seemed to run fine, however, since I accidentally broke my OS yesterday (sudo apt-get remove python wasn't a very good idea) I thought that I might as well upgrade the distribution.

I tried Ubuntu 18 and 16. Both installations went fine. However, when I boot on drive after installation, **I can't get past login. Screen becomes black and my laptop reboots.**

I'm currently on my fresh Ubuntu 18 that I booted with nomodeset. Native Radeon module didn't work, neither did Oibaf. I haven't tried AMPDGPU-PRO, but it didn't work last time I tried on Xenial (login loop).
[And there are no proprietary driver for this GPU past Ubuntu 14](https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064) (I couldn't get fglrx to work on 14 anyway, that's why I used Oibaf instead)

There might also be a power problem but I haven't investigated this beyond disabling acpi.

Is there a way to fix this problem ? (other than downgrading to Ubuntu 14 or permanently add nomodeset to GRUB)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to grub radeon.modeset=0 to this line :

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

that it reads :

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0"

works better for me than "nomodeset"

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me, UBUNTU 20.04

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0"